# Design 2 JK Flip Flops without Switch Input to K

Tags: flipflop, ttl

I have a lab for my Intro to Hardware Course due today. We use TTL. (True= 5v, False= 0v)

```
Design a 4 bit register using 2 D Flip Flops(Chip 7474) and 2 JK Flip Flops(Chip7473).
Only use 4 Input Switches. Using a Pushbutton for Clock, and another Push Button for 
Clear, which will go to all Flip Flops. The output of the register will be measured using 
LEDs.
```

So we can't use a Switch Input for the K of the 2 JK Flip Flops. My teacher gave me the hint of looking at K on the JK Flip Flop Truth Table/Characteristic Table.
K is like Z on it, where it's always alternating between 0 and 1.

My thought is to connect it to the Clock. Can someone confirm or deny this thought process?

Answer (score 1):

I can deny that is what the instructor has in mind.

Look at the **excitation table** for the [J-K flip-flop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#JK_flip-flop).

[image]

There are four possibilities of input and current state, and you have both the current
state and the inverse of the current state available.

See if you can see how you could connect J and K so that after a clock \$Q_{next}\$ is always the same as the input, regardless of the current value of Q.

You might notice that J is more closely related to the the output after the clock than K, which causes the output to go low or toggle when it is high.

Comment: Hmmm... Would I connect K to the output of Q?

Comment: Looks like a pretty good bet. What are you going to do with J?

Comment: J is connected to an Input Logic Switch. So I can control what J is.

Comment: Yup, you got it!